# PHP Regex to allow special characters but no any space

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I have the following Regex to allow alphanumeric characters and following special characters

```
/()-
```

The Regular expression is

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9-()-/]/
```

The complete method is

```
public function ValidateNumber($number)
{
    $return = true;
    $matches = null;
    if((preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9-/()-]/', $number, $matches)) > 0)
    {
       $return = false; 
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Above method woks fine, but also return TRUE if number has space. When i remove '/' from Regex then if number has 'space' in it then it returns FALSE.

So seems some issue with '/' in Regex.

Please advise some solution

Comment: You need to escape special characters. It helps to use websites such as http://regex101.com when designing regular expressions. You can tweak, test, and see exactly what the code is doing much quicker than testing it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to allow alphanumeric characters and the the above mentioned special characters `/()-`,

```
^[A-Za-z0-9()\/-]+$
```

`^` inside(at the strat of)  chracter class means not. So your regex allows any character not of the ones mentioned inside the character class. And also it's better to escape `/` inside the character class and always consider in putting `-` at the start or end of the character class. To allow one ore more characters which was mentioned inside char class then you need to add `+` after the character class.

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
[A-Za-z0-9()\/-]+        any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z',
                         '0' to '9', '(', ')', '\/', '-' (1 or more
                         times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Comment: so you mean as i m using ^ inside [] then A-Z will also not considered valid?

Comment: but it is returning true for number like asd23423

Comment: `^` only at the start of char class means not. You need to include `^` start and end `$` patterns.

Comment: ok i got it , the function is checking for character which is not given in Regex and if it is not there then it set it to FALSE

Comment: not that `^` outside the character class means start of the line. See http://regex101.com/r/pS9tI3/5

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
$theregex = '~^[a-z0-9/()-]+$~i';
if (preg_match($theregex, $yourstring)) {
    // Yes! It matches!
    } 
else { // nah, no luck...
     }
```

**Explanation**

- The `i` flag at the end makes it case-insensitive
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- To match a hyphen in a `[character class]`, place it at the beginning or at the end so that it is not ambiguous, since it may indicate a range, as in `a-d`
- `[a-z0-9/()-]+` matches one or more letter, digit, slash, parenthesis or hyphen
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: +1 good use of `~` as delimiter.. also please highlight the fact that OP had wrongly used unescaped hyphen in between the character class.

Comment: Thanks, @anubhava. Added this to the explanation: To match a hyphen in a `[character class]`, place it at the beginning or at the end so that it is not ambiguous, since it may indicate a range, as in `a-d`

Answer (score 0):

You should escape `/` in your regex using `\/`

But you should probably use the following expression to do what you want:

```
([^A-Za-z0-9-()-\/])+
```

So the whole method could look like this:

```
public function ValidateNumber($number)
{
    if (preg_match('/([^A-Za-z0-9-()-\/])+/', $number)) {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

without extra variables.

In above case you try to find any characters that don't match (here `^` means characters that don't match) your criteria and if any of them is found `preg_match` return 1 so it means that number is invalid.

However you can also use another expression to achieve what you want - you don't find characters that don't match (as in previous example) but you check if the whole string matches your criteria using `^` as the beginning (in this case it means the beginning of the string - meaning is different that the one in previous solution) and `$` as the end of the string to check the whole string. In this case your method could look like this:

```
public function ValidateNumber($number)
{
    if (preg_match('/^([A-Za-z0-9-()-\/]+)$/', $number)) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For Much better understanding and learning regex for the further work you can visit the below links

[Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

[Useful regular expression tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332800/useful-regular-expression-tutorial)

Regular expressions tutorials

And one of the best and easy one and my favourite is

http://www.9lessons.info/2013/10/understanding-regular-expression.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+9lesson+%289lessons%29

very nice and easy tutorial for the beginners