# PHP regex to Find & Replace specific string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, find

Well,

I've some texts like this below:

> < Jens > is my name. I play < Football >. I saw < Steffy > Yesterday. Yeah, We will be < Together > For sure.

And I just want all the texts between '<' & '>' (including <>) to be bold programmatically using Regular Expression (Preferably) or any other method. This is a kind of Find & Replace. So after the operation texts should be :

> **< Jens >** is my name. I play **< Football >**. I saw **< Steffy >** Yesterday. Yeah, We will be **< Together >** For sure.

Comment: try `<[^<>]*>` regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback):

```
<?php
// header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$test = <<<TXT
< Jens > is my name. I play < Football >.
I saw < Steffy > Yesterday. Yeah, We will be < Together > For sure.
TXT;

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<[^>]+>/',
    function($matches){
        return '<b>' . htmlspecialchars($matches[0]) . '</b>';
    },
    $test
);

print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output:**

> **< Jens >** is my name. I play **< Football >**. I saw **<
>   Steffy >** Yesterday. Yeah, We will be **< Together >** For sure.

Comment: Why need a callback? Wouldn't `preg_replace` and as replacement `'<b>\0</b>'` be convenient?

Comment: It gets rendered in browser just like this : <b>< Jens ></b> is my name. I play <b>< Football ></b>.
I saw <b>< Steffy ></b> Yesterday. Yeah, We will be <b>< Together ></b> For sure. No bold!

Comment: @Jonny5 I do have a strong feeling, that after this "Find & Replace" OP might want to have more control over situation.

Comment: @MaxinBits remove `header()` string

Comment: @MaxinBits Yea, maybe OP want to use `htmlspecialchars` for the stuff inside `<b>...</b>` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `preg_replace`:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(<[^>]*>)/', '<b>$1</b>', $str);
```

`<b>< Jens ></b> is my name. I play <b>< Football ></b>. I saw <b>< Steffy ></b> Yesterday. Yeah, We will be <b>< Together ></b> For sure.`

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aW3uE8/1)

Comment: \b or <b>? I'm on browser not in CLI.

Comment: Yes that's correct, my HTML skills are pretty poor :(

Comment: its ok..np..Cheers..:)

Answer (score 1):

For Much better understanding and learning regex for the further work you can visit the below links

Learning Regular Expressions

[Useful regular expression tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

[Regular expressions tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332800/useful-regular-expression-tutorial)

And one of the best and easy one and my favourite is

[http://www.9lessons.info/2013/10/understanding-regular-expression.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+9lesson+%289lessons%29](http://www.9lessons.info/2013/10/understanding-regular-expression.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%209lesson%20%289lessons%29)

very nice and easy tutorial for the beginners